# angular2 typescript fetch data takes long

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

I have this service:

```
getPOheadersWithPromise(): Promise<POheader[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.getDataUrl).toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
}
```

and read as:

```
fetchPOheaders(): void {
        this.poheaderService.getPOheadersWithPromise()
            .then(res => {
                this.poheaders = res;
                this.Total();
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
       }
```

and about 100k records (26mb) takes 1.2 minutes to load. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Retrieve less than 100k records at a time?

Comment: Use paging/chunking. Create a backend that supports this (there are existing frameworks like oData that can support this). Retrieve only what you need. Does the user need to see 100K records at a time? Probably not. But 50 or 100 at a time with the option to page, sort, and possibly filter would give the user a more rich experience.